# Unable to upload report to report server

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, ssrs-2008, report, reportserver

I am unable to upload report to report server.

It does not throw any errors when I build and deploy (show as succeeded) but I don't see the report on portal. I refreshed couple of times as well.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Is your folder path correct? it could be that it is deploying to somewhere you're not expecting.

Comment: you are right I was deploying to reportserver - ap12 instead of ap11..Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to answer it so it gets tagged as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your folder path correct? it could be that it is deploying to somewhere you're not expecting.

[image]